# How to insert data in a table from another table?

Tags: sql

I have a dynamic table which includes some dynamic and constant (`[Id]` `[DecreeGuid]`) columns:

It might have a lot of columns but in this case I'll demonstrate table in a small scale of columns that would be like this:

[image]

and there is another table that I'm going to get values from it:
[image]

I wanted to know how can insert `[Value]` and `[decreeGuid]` from second table in to dynamic table under condition where column name of dynamic table equal rows of `[Title]`  column of second table

Comment: It depends on your dbms, if it's ```mySQL```, do: ```INSERT INTO tablename(col1, coln) SELECT col1, coln FROM tablename WHERE clause```

Comment: Have also an eye on https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out that how to solve my problem and I decided to share my answer.
I use PIVOTE to get values in a table like this:

```
 DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX)
    DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
    
    --Get distinct values of the PIVOT Column
    SELECT @ColumnName= ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','')
           + QUOTENAME(Title)
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Title FROM Temp2) AS Title
    
    SET @SQL=' SELECT * into Temp3 FROM (SELECT Title,
    Value,
    DecreeGuid, [Type]'
    SET @SQL = @SQL +' from Temp2 ) AS S
    
        PIVOT(MAx(S.Value)
              FOR Title IN (' + @ColumnName +')) AS PVTTable'
    
    EXEC (@SQL)
    
    GO
    
    DECLARE @ColumnNames AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @SQL1 nvarchar(MAX)
    
    SELECT @ColumnNames= ISNULL(@ColumnNames + ',','')
           + QUOTENAME(name)
    FROM (SELECT name FROM sys.columns WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[prs_DecreeBookmarkExtra]') AND name <> N'Id') AS Title
    
    SET @SQL1='INSERT INTO prs_DecreeBookmarkExtra  SELECT '+@ColumnNames+' FROM Temp3 WHERE [TYPE] = 1'
    exec (@SQL1)
    
    GO
```

Answer (score 2):

You need INSERT SELECT statement, something like this:

INSERT INTO table2 (column1, column2, column3, ...)
SELECT column1, column2, column3, ...
FROM table1
WHERE condition;

**Edited**

Up to your requirements it should be:

```
INSERT INTO dynamic_table (decree_title, decree_guid) SELECT value, decree_guid FROM customer WHERE condition
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I think there's a misunderstanding here, your answer in correct when you know how many columns does the table have, this is dynamic table and it might have different columns in different customers. for instance, it has Id, DecreeTitle, DecreeGuid in a customer and  Id, DecreeTitle, DecreeGuid, EffectiveDate in another customer. I want to run a specific script that works in all customers.